# How to store password from preference page in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to store a password for updating in preference page field.

I did this using ISecurePreferences but the problem is the node doesn't exists after the instance is closed.

```
@Override
public boolean performOk() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("perform ok");
    ISecurePreferences root = SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault();

    //System.out.println("Children names: "+root.);

    ISecurePreferences node = root.node("password");
    try {
        System.out.println("Password to store: "+passwordField.getStringValue());
        node.put("password",passwordField.getStringValue(),true);
        System.out.println("stored");


    } catch (StorageException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Storage failed");
    }       
    return true;
}
```

In preference initializer :

```
@Override
public void initializeDefaultPreferences() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Initializing preferences");

    //IPreferenceStore prefStore = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
    ISecurePreferences root = SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault();
    if(root.nodeExists("password")){
        ISecurePreferences node = root.node("password");                    
        try {
            System.out.println("password taken: "+node.get("password",""));
        } catch (StorageException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("node doesn't exists");
    }
}
```

In the same execution of the Eclipse I can store and retrieve the password.

Can you help me indicating what I have to do in order to persist the informations between instances ?

Comment: `flush` - Saves the tree of secure preferences to the persistent storage. This method can be called on any node in the secure preference tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to call the `flush()` method of `ISecurePreferences` to save the preferences you have set.

Comment: That was, can you tell me, in order to set the defaults I can do this using ISecurePreferences or I have to use IPreferenceStore with setDefault ?

Comment: ISecurePreferences is not related to the normal preferences. Your preference page should override `performDefaults` and do something different for the defaults.